# How to return an array of JsonModel

Tags: php, api, rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2

From my controller which extends Zend's `AbstractRestfulController`, I'm trying to return an array of `JsonModel` but I just get back HTML.

An very simplistic example of what I'm trying to do is here:

```
$models = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    $model = new MyJsonModel();
    $model->setDocument($someObj);
    $models[] = $model;
}

return Json::encode($models);
```

Where `MyJsonModel` is just a subclass of `JsonModel` that adds a "document" property that is serialized as JSON.

Ultimately, I'm simply looking for something like:

```
[
  {
    key:val      
  },
  {
    key:val
  },
  {
    key:val
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add in your module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => [
    'strategies' => [ViewJsonStrategy],
    // ... your config ...
]
```

More information at https://akrabat.com/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alain's answer you can try following:

Firstly check if you have json import

```
Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
```

Followed by the creation of your "array" then simply return your array as json

```
return new JsonModel($model);
```